# How to fix CISCO Anyconnect 12 seconds timeout bug?

Tags: windows-7, cisco-anyconnect

In reference to this thread: https://help.duo.com/s/article/1146?language=en_US, is there a way to increase the 12 seconds default timeout in Cisco Anyconnect <= 4.7 without establishing a first successful connection? I have set the FQDN of the host adress and the connection timeout to 60 seconds in my profile but Anyconnect still ignores it. I need version 4.7 to install on an old Windows 7 client.

Comment: This [support article](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/164226/vip-enterprise-gateway-cisco-anyconnect.html) says this error is caused by a bad host-name in the config file.

Comment: The HostAddress of the profile is already a valid FQDN but the AuthenticationTimeout is still ignored.